# Why do we need API automation?

Tags: webautomation, web-api-testing

As a initial phase of development we are need to perform API but why API automation is required after the product gone live. Is there any specific reason.

Because functional automation should be sufficient to track the functionality of the web site.

How does functional testing differ from API testing?

Comment: What do you mean by "API automation"? Are you really talking about a webserver that exposes an API which should be tested? If your client has required to perform testing, why not ask the client directly which parts he wants to have tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional testing focuses on validating software features and behavior (usually against specification documents generated by business and development teams).  This black-box testing is often performed from the end-user perspective, and it can also include usability and UI testing in addition to feature validation.

API testing focuses on testing an application programming interface, which--at a high level--allows software systems to communicate.  Instead of testing from an end-user point-of-view, the testing focuses on the mechanisms of the API.  Generally, this involves making calls to the API and validating the response (e.g. returning the appropriate status code, correctly modifying a resource, etc).

Obviously, this is a superficial summary.  But the takeaway is this: with functional testing, you're testing how the application behaves; with API testing, you're testing the internal mechanisms that drive application behavior.

Answer (score 0):

API testing is required to test the system backend services. Application UI usually receives data directly from DB or from API to abstract the system internal structure etc. Also, other external systems need to interact with your system so API is the most powerful way to exchange data between two or more systems.

You can test and automate the APIs using `Rest-Assured(Java)` or `RestSharp(C#)`. It's very easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

API testing is usually done when the UI is not ready. Moreover, The response time is faster than when compared with Functional testing using UI. It also helps one understand the response in various scenarios. One doesn't have to depend on any technology, the API URI is enough to check the functionality

Answer (score 0):

1. In the regression phase API Automation is required. Whenever these is some deployment in the existing application. Team can execute automation suite anytime.
2. The other reasons is, going forward - CI/CD implementation is required for any kind of API Project. In order to achieve continuous delivery, Automation is the first step.
3. In the Agile methodology, Automation should start with the initial phases and changes can be done anytime in the scripts.